# Angular 9 ngx-translate universal how to load translations before app is loaded?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I have angular universal + pwa + ngx-translate app and now I have a little glitch/bug. When i load my app i can see for like 300-500ms all untranslated texts (keys) like `common.back`, `common.next`and then they change to translation values like **next** and **back**.

**How to load translation before page load on angular universal ?**

This is my setup :

**app.module :**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

imports: [
...
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
...
]
```

**app.server.module :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'autorent' }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

**app.browser.module :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'autorent' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppBrowserModule { }
```

If you need another info, which I doubt, just write in comments and I will provide.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Easy, use a [`TranslateHttpLoader`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.browser.module.ts#L12-L22) in your [`AppBrowserModule`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.ts#L47), and a [`TranslateJsonLoader`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.browser.module.ts#L12-L22) in your `AppServerModule`